# How are Ajax/Fetch calls different on production server vs. runserver for Django app?

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, heroku, django-views

**--UPDATE SOLVED--**

The problem wasn't my code, it was the HTTP server library I was using. Gunicorn apparently didn't work the way I needed it to out of the box, so this post below helped point me to **Waitress** as an alternative **HTTP server library**. Now my progress updates the way it's supposed to.

Link: http://blog.etianen.com/blog/2014/01/19/gunicorn-heroku-django/

=============================================

**How things are working on my development runserver**:

I have a Django app that updates a progress html tag using Ajax requests (currently I am using POST but I have used GET successfully as well on my development runserver). Everything works great. The Ajax request calls a function in my view.py that returns a JsonResponse with the updated data from my business logic happening in views. I am using setInterval with setTimeout to control the number of calls and clearInterval when I reach certain values.

**Production deployment to Heroku**:

I am currently trying to deploy to Heroku and have been 99% successful. My template renders correctly, so I can see my page and submit the form for processing. The 1% problem here is that my Ajax requests are not getting updated data and I don't know why. It's like my Ajax requests are just getting the initialized variable values of zero and continue to return those values.

I am console.logging the JSON returned from the Ajax call:

```
{games: 0, progress: 0, percentage: 0}
{games: 0, progress: 0, percentage: 0}
{games: 0, progress: 0, percentage: 0}
{games: 0, progress: 0, percentage: 0}
```

This JSON just gets returned over and over again on the Heroku production server.

On my local runserver I get something like this with the local server showing me the progress it's making:

```
{games: 5, progress: 1, percentage: 0}
{games: 5, progress: 2, percentage: 0}
{games: 5, progress: 3, percentage: 20}
{games: 5, progress: 4, percentage: 40}
{games: 5, progress: 5, percentage: 40}
```

I've done a lot of research into this and actually just switched from Ajax to using the Fetch() (sorry for the switch mid-post from ajax to fetch, but I don't think the problem has to do with method used). **Is there some setting I'm not aware of that makes a difference for updating a page real time in production?** Here is my current Fetch method:

```
$("#myButton").click(function call_fetch() {
        fetch('/progress/', {
            method: 'post',
            headers: {
              'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken
            },
            credentials: "same-origin"
        })
          .then(
            function(response) {
              if (response.status !== 200) {
                console.log('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' +
                  response.status);
                return;
              }

              // Examine the text in the response
              response.json().then(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                document.getElementById("progressBar").max = data["games"];
                document.getElementById("progressBar").value = data["progress"];
                document.getElementById("progressGames").innerHTML = "Game " + data["progress"];
                document.getElementById("percentage").innerHTML = "Percentage Rate: " + data["percentage"] + "%";
                if (data["progress"] == data["games"] && data["progress"] != "0") {
                    clearInterval(interval_id);
                    document.forms.myForm.myButton.disabled = false;
                }
              });
            }
          )
          .catch(function(err) {
            console.log('Fetch Error :-S', err);
          });
        var interval_id = setInterval(setTimeout(call_fetch,2000), 2000);
    });
```

I don't use class based views if that makes a difference? I am just using 2 different view functions. One that renders the index.html page and one for progress updating that returns the JsonResponse. I'm using Python-3.6, Django-1.10.6 for deploying to Heroku which is working. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think it'd be helpful to see your `view.py`

Comment: I actually just solved it ironically right after posting this. Smh. It wasn't my code, it was the HTTP server library I was using (gunicorn) that was the problem. I switched to using waitress and that solved my problem. I'll update the post. This link was helpful:

http://blog.etianen.com/blog/2014/01/19/gunicorn-heroku-django/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem wasn't my code, it was the HTTP server library I was using. Gunicorn apparently didn't work the way I needed it to out of the box, so this post below helped point me to **Waitress** as an alternative **HTTP server library**. Now my progress updates the way it's supposed to.

Link: http://blog.etianen.com/blog/2014/01/19/gunicorn-heroku-django/